# Window does not scroll to bottom on document ready

Tags: jquery, html

I have a webpage with some jQuery that should make it scroll to the bottom when the page loads:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
    });
</script>
```

For some reason, when the page loads, it does not scroll to the bottom. But when I do this:

```
<form id="messageinput">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
<script>
    $("#messageinput").submit(function() {
        $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly. Any idea how to fix this? Is there a better way to have it scroll to the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried by adding 10000000000000px besides document height?

Comment: @StupidKid yeah, I did, also didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like animation that doesn't abruptly stop, try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
  scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 
  1400, 
  "linear"
);
```

If you don't care about animation use this:

```
$(myScrollingElement).scrollTop(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height()); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
});
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try here it works, same as you posted?

Have you added jquery or have some errors?